# How to get indexes from JSON and put them into the HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatables

I have a following question:

I have a JS code for fetching JSON, which available on some URL, and drawing a table. JSON looks like this:

```
[{"price":12437,
  "quantity":4,
  "name":"\u0421\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043c\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0431\u043b\u043e\u043a"},
 {"price":17043,
  "quantity":6,
  "name":"\u0412\u043e\u0434\u0430 \u0431\u0443\u0442\u0438\u043b\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430\u043d\u043d\u0430\u044f"},         
 {"price":10594,
  "quantity":4,
  "name":"\u0428\u043a\u0430\u0444 \u043a\u043d\u0438\u0436\u043d\u044b\u0439"},
 {"price":17965,
  "quantity":7,
  "name":"\u0427\u0430\u0439\u043d\u0438\u043a \u044d\u043b\u0435\u043a\u0442\u0440\u0438\u0447\u0435\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439"},
 {"price":14280,
  "quantity":5,
  "name":"\u041b\u0430\u0437\u0435\u0440\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u043f\u0440\u0438\u043d\u0442\u0435\u0440"}]
```

The code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/3p5ge0h9/.
I need to get the indexes of every object in JSON and put them into the HTML table (into the column called "ID"). How to do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try passing index from the `for` loop to your row render function.

Comment: so what have you already tried? Post a minified version of your relevant code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem like a 20yco:

```
 drawTable(data);
        function drawTable(data) {
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                drawRow(i+1, data[i]);
            }
        }

        function drawRow(index, rowData) {
            let row = $("<tr class='table-data' />"),
                productSum = rowData.quantity * rowData.price;
            $(".products_table tbody").append(row);
            row.append($("<td>" + index + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.quantity + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.price + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + productSum + "</td>"));
        }
```

You can see ful table here: https://sashajarvi.github.io/products-table-json/table.html

Answer (score 1):

try to use `for`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < your_array.length; i++){
    // log each from your array
    // where 'i' is the index that you try to find
    console.log(your_array[i]);

  }
}
```

or take a look at the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20yco/vo6c5k9x/1/) where i add `index` in your all functions

here:

```
    function drawTable(data) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            drawRow(i, data[i]);
        }
    }
```

and here:

```
        function drawRow(index, rowData) {
            let row = $("<tr class='table-data' />"),
                productSum = rowData.quantity * rowData.price;
            $(".products_table tbody").append(row);
            row.append($("<td>" + index + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.name + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.quantity + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + rowData.price + "</td>"));
            row.append($("<td>" + productSum + "</td>"));
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer helped me